# jQuery/Javascript if value is in array, continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have data that is in an array, these are the ID's for users that have commented on said post. I want to compare this array with the id of the user, and if their id is in this array, continue with the code.

my array looks like:

```
({0:"1", 3:"6"}) // 1 and 6 are the ID's that I want to work with.
```

So I want to do something like:

```
var array = ({0:"1", 3:"6"});
var userID = 6;
if(in(array)==userID)
{

 ///you are in the list, so do whatever
 }
```

Comment: Your data isn't an array, but a JSON object with properties 0 and 3.  Is that really how your data is getting to your web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
var count = 0;
for (var k in haystack) {
    if (haystack.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
       ++count;
    }
}
for (var i in haystack) {
    if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
}
return false;
}
```

​

See : http://jsfiddle.net/ryN6U/1/

If will not work with your object :)

Comment: I fixed the function and added a jsFiddle example.

Comment: when I do it it always returns false

Comment: Oh thanks, I realized I was doing something wrong on my end though, but now it's all working.

Answer (score 1):

Instancing your array like that will not create an array, but an object. Normally, you instantiate arrays in javascript like this:

```
var arr = [17, 4711];
```

Checking for a value using [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
arr.indexOf(17); // => 0
arr.indexOf(4711); // => 1
arr.indexOf(42); // => -1
```

Pushing:

```
arr.push(42);
arr.indexOf(42); // => 2
```

`Array.indexOf` is not in IE < 9, so I suggest you look into using [a shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your object and check it against your userid. Something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myArray = ({0:"1", 3:"6"});
var userId = 6;
for(vals in myArray){
    if(userId == myArray[vals]){
        alert("userid exists in array");
    }
}
```

});

Comment: this logic does not work or the code itself is not working? You probably have to update the variable names. The ones in my code are different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

When testing against an array I would use [jQuery's inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

if your looking for the first item in an object with a certain value look at this thread

[json index of property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585085/json-index-of-property-value)